# Move-AzureDeployment PowerShell Cmdlet fails when nothing deployed to Production slot

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm using the Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets v0.6.7 from here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/downloads/

When I run the following command:

```
Move-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $AzureServiceName
```

I get the following error:

```
Move-AzureDeployment : There was no endpoint listening at https://management.core.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/services/hostedservices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/deploymentslots/Production that could accept the message.
```

The error is somewhat correct, there is only a deployment in my Staging slot.  However, the documentation for Move-AzureDeployment (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152834.aspx) states:

> If there is a deployment in the staging environment and no deployment
>   in the production environment, the deployment will move to production.

The preceding Azure PowerShell Cmdlets in the same script, such as New-AzureDeployment, execute successfully.  I start the script by using Set-AzureSubscription to configure the subscription info and certificate.

Not sure what I'm missing, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well and resorted to using the REST API for swapping. Here is a sample in case anyone is interested.

```
    $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://management.core.windows.net/$global:SubscriptionId/services/hostedservices/$serviceName")

    $webRequestContent = ("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><Swap xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure""><Production>{0}</Production><SourceDeployment>{1}</SourceDeployment></Swap>" -f $productionDeploymentName, $stagingDeploymentName)
    $webRequest.Method = "POST"
    $webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add($global:ManagementCertificate)
    $webRequest.ContentType = "application/xml"
    $webRequest.ContentLength = $webRequestContent.length
    $webRequest.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-03-01")
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    $writer.Write($webRequestContent)
    $writer.Close()

    $webResponse = $webRequest.GetResponse()
    WaitForDeploymentState $serviceName 'Production' 'Running'
    WaitForRoleInstancesState $serviceName 'Production' 'ReadyRole'
```

Comment: Being only a casual PowerShell user, it wasn't obvious to me how to load the certificate. I worked it out, eventually. I hope I can save others reading this some time. You can use: $global:ManagementCertificate=gci cert:\CurrentUser\My\<thumbprint> where <thumbprint> is the cert thumbprint. This assumes the cert is installed in your Personal store.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug. I created an issue here:

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/785

Answer (score 0):

I found this when I hit the same problem.

In my script, if I want to run the `Move-AzureDeployment` I first check the Production slot, if it has content then I switch (having already deployed to staging earlier in the script).

In the case where Production is empty I re-deploy the current package to the Production Slot, I could optimize it to use the azure storage but it'll do for today.

**In short; the docs are either wrong or there is a bug, you cannot use this cmdlet if Production is empty.**